# Return indices of a variable

Tags: programming

I want to define a function f such that $f(x[1,2]^{-1/3})=\{1,2\}, f(x[1,2])=\{1,2\}, f(x[1])=\{1\}, f(x[1]^{1/3}) =\{1\}$, f(x)=empty set. How could I do this in Mathematica? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how versatile this is but it works on your examples,

```
f[a_[b__]^c_] := {b};
f[a_[b__]] := {b}
f[a_] := {}

f /@ {x[1, 2]^(-1/3), x[1, 2], x[1], x[1]^(1/3), x}
(* {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1}, {1}, {}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit more general.

```
f[_?AtomQ] := {}
f[_[x___]] := {x}
f[_[_[x___], ___]] := {x}
```